# Is it possible to build transcoding&streaming applications using Stream Processing Engines such as Storm?

Tags: java, video-streaming, real-time, transcoding, apache-storm

I am curious to know whether it is possible or good idea to build such a system using SPE. In our lab we developed **Hadoop** based transcoding and streaming service on a cluster of 20 nodes using `mkvtoolnix` and `Xuggler` libraries for transcoding. And it works pretty well. However, I am not quite familiar with Storm's usage in Multimedia Manipulation like transcoding. I just know that **Storm** is heavily used in Real-time Big Data Analytics. 
My system is intended to process (transcode from various video formats into mpeg4) real-time video data coming from video sensors and at the same time it should be able to stream the transcoded chunks of video to the dashboard.

How can I achieve this using Storm, or any suggestions how to build such a system is very welcome!

Comment: If you have a running implementation using Hadoop why do you want to switch to Storm? What "nature" does you MapReduce program have? Is it a bunch of Map-Reduce jobs or a single Map-Reduce or even map-only job? How do mkvtoolnix and Xuggler work? Do the apply to a video stream as a whole or on single frames? Or maybe are some windowing technique used?

Comment: basically, it is a chain of MR jobs, and they apply in a single frame rate

Comment: the reason of moving from working Hadoop instance to Storm is my prof's wish, he does not care about it is right or not, he just wants me to implement it using Storm. But I am not sure whether Storm is suitable for this kind of usage

Answer (score 1):

Using Storm should be fairly simple and seems to be a good fit. You can encode each frame as a single tuple and translate all your map and reduce code to **bolts** within a single topology. As connection pattern you can use `shuffleGrouping` for "map-bolts" and `fieldGrouping` for "reduce-bolts".